# Use of ‘such a lonely work’ instead of ‘such lonely work’

Tags: articles

A sentence of William Zinsser in "On writing Well" goes like this:  “Writing is such lonely work that I try to keep myself cheered up.”

Does it make any difference or is it a wrong usage if I use ‘such a lonely work’ instead of ‘such lonely work’ in the above sentence?

Answer (score 2):

*Work* in this sense, "the job that a person does", (Oxford ALD) is normally uncountable. Countable *work* normally refers  to a book, painting, musical composition, etc, a work of art.

Only the uncountable noun is appropriate in your context.